# AWS Athena: casting float to int return round instead of integer part

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Using AWS Athena, I am running the query

```
SELECT cast(0.1 as int), cast(0.4 as int),cast(0.5 as int), cast(0.9 as int)
```

I am getting: 0, 0, 1, 1

I would expect to get: 0, 0, 0, 0

Is the expected behaviour of cast to round a number?

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate, why would you expect casting a float to an integer would take the floor of the number?

Comment: all other programming languages I know (python, Scala, C,...) behave like floor for casting to int, not like round. The same is expected according W3School (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_cast), or spark (spark.sql("select cast(0.9 as int)").show()). It seems a bit dangerous to port sql

Comment: The SQL specification leaves it up to the implementation to choose whether to round or truncate in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. You can just use the floor function to achieve the result you are aiming for:

```
SELECT cast(0.1 as int), cast(0.4 as int), cast(floor(0.5) as int), cast(floor(0.9) as int)
```